# Django failed with Authentication credentials were not provided

Tags: django, authentication

I have tried to use Django basic Authentication feature to verify username(test) and password(test).

It works from my local:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/json; indent=4' -u test:test 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/checkuser/'
{
    "detail": "Account authorized."
}
```

But it failed from production site:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/json; indent=4' -u test:test 'https://production.fake/api/checkuser/'
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

I have tried to enable WSGIPassAuthorization from production server, but it does not help.

It seems to me that somehow the username and password did not really pass through, but cannot figure out how.

**It works if I use web browser to access https://production.fake/api/checkuser/**

Any advice to troubleshoot will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: We need details on your web server configuration... Are you sure the web server requests users to send credentials?

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with web server configuration, it was setup by IT.  How to check if web server requests users to send credentials?

Comment: The credentials authentication checks was developed in Django.